# List of ABAP protected type names

Tags: abap

Out of curiosity, I tried to create an ABAP interface with name `object`.  The compiler gives the error message `"OBJECT" is a protected type name and therefore cannot be used for a user's own type definitions.`

While this check is certainly a good idea, I could not find a reference to `protected type name` in the ABAP Keyword documentation.  Are there others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [naming conventions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abennaming_conventions.htm) indicate the possible names additionally to the mandatory naming "convention":

- *The names of predefined ABAP types or predefined data objects must not be used for data types or data objects.*

  - NB: I tried names of predefined data objects, they are allowed for data types, so I guess "respectively" is to be understood implicitly.
- *Self-defined data types must not have the name of a built-in ABAP type. This applies to type definitions in the ABAP language and in the ABAP Dictionary.*

Concerning the generic types, only those made of one word are forbidden, i.e. `HASHED`, `INDEX`, `SORTED`, and `STANDARD` are allowed (and also `REF`):

- `ANY`, `C`, `CLIKE`, `CSEQUENCE`, `DATA`, `DECFLOAT`, `N`, `NUMERIC`, `OBJECT`, `P`, `SIMPLE`, `TABLE`, `X`, `XSEQUENCE`

Other types are protected like the built-in concrete (i.e. not generic) types (error `<XXXX> is a protected type name and therefore cannot be used for a user's own type definitions`):

- `D`, `DECFLOAT16`, `DECFLOAT34`, `F`, `I`, `STRING`, `T`, `XSTRING`
- `CURSOR`
- Obsolete types `1` and `2` (their names are also forbidden inside classes and interfaces because the name must start with A-Z, underscore).

Other types may be forbidden (error `Type <XXXX> is reserved for future further developments of the ABAP language. Choose another name.`) like:

- `INT`, `INT1`, `INT2`, `INT4`, `INT8`

The list is not exhaustive. I didn't find an official list in the ABAP documentation nor in the SAP support Web site.

NB: tests done in a 7.52 system

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive answer. Sorry, I already have accepted another answer as most helpful one.

Comment: I'm not asking for best answer or useful answer, but for your information, you can still change your choice and vote for an answer as being useful or not useful. See [more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Didn't know that I can undo that.

Answer (score 3):

The generic data types, which cannot be used for naming:

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenbuilt_in_types_generic.htm

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create all of your object or program or table ect.. is to put the Z or the Y before the name you want to give:

Object have to been Zobject or Yobject or ZY-YZobject

Often, we use the Z and then the module wich it refers: ZSD_OBJECT